# "New Tab" button is missing in Tab Bar in Firefox 17

Tags: firefox, browser

After the recent update to Firefox 17, the New tab button is missing from the tab bar.
Some forum posts say, we need to drag the button from the toolbar layout page. But the button isnt available in the toolbar layout window also. Check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Try clicking "restore default set". Otherwise, look for a + icon on one of your toolbars when you are on the customise toolbar screen. The + icon is the new tab button.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar Thanks. "Restore Default Set" brought back the "+" button in the tab bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the *Restore Default Set* button to regain all of the buttons.